# How can I get specific xml tags using BeautifulSoup in python 3.5?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Here is my Chicago XML file:
route name="red">

```
<route name = "red">
<train>
<rn>830</rn>
<destSt>30089</destSt>
<destNm>95th/Dan Ryan</destNm>
<trDr>5</trDr>
<nextStaId>41000</nextStaId>
<nextStpId>30194</nextStpId>
<nextStaNm>Cermak-Chinatown</nextStaNm>
<prdt>20180117 22:41:16</prdt>
<arrT>20180117 22:42:16</arrT>
<isApp>1</isApp>
<isDly>0</isDly>
<flags/>
<lat>41.85532</lat>
<lon>-87.63133</lon>
<heading>176</heading>

<route name="blue">
<train>
<rn>134</rn>
<destSt>30077</destSt>
<destNm>Forest Park</destNm>
<trDr>5</trDr>
<nextStaId>40570</nextStaId>
<nextStpId>30112</nextStpId>
<nextStaNm>California</nextStaNm>
<prdt>20180117 22:40:47</prdt>
<arrT>20180117 22:42:47</arrT>
<isApp>0</isApp>
<isDly>0</isDly>
<flags/>
<lat>41.92528</lat>
<lon>-87.70238</lon>
<heading>122</heading>
</train>
```

I was able to using .find function to extract the first train number and more info with that train, but now I want to extract the tag for one train(and the date for that specific train) for the 'route = blue' paragraph... How can I do that? I have trouble with it because every tag are the same.

My current code to extract the first tag goes like:

```
train = XML.find('rn')
print(train)  #just a gist of the code
```

any solutions?  I am using BeautifulSoup4

Comment: so you want to extract train number and date for each route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change your xml slightly because it wasn't well formed, but assuming the xml looks something like this:

```
<data>
  <route name="red">
    <train>
      <rn>830</rn>
      <destSt>30089</destSt>
      <destNm>95th/Dan Ryan</destNm>
      <trDr>5</trDr>
      <nextStaId>41000</nextStaId>
      <nextStpId>30194</nextStpId>
      <nextStaNm>Cermak-Chinatown</nextStaNm>
      <prdt>20180117 22:41:16</prdt>
      <arrT>20180117 22:42:16</arrT>
      <isApp>1</isApp>
      <isDly>0</isDly>
      <flags/>
      <lat>41.85532</lat>
      <lon>-87.63133</lon>
      <heading>176</heading>
    </train>
  </route>
  <route name="blue">
    <train>
      <rn>134</rn>
      <destSt>30077</destSt>
      <destNm>Forest Park</destNm>
      <trDr>5</trDr>
      <nextStaId>40570</nextStaId>
      <nextStpId>30112</nextStpId>
      <nextStaNm>California</nextStaNm>
      <prdt>20180117 22:40:47</prdt>
      <arrT>20180117 22:42:47</arrT>
      <isApp>0</isApp>
      <isDly>0</isDly>
      <flags/>
      <lat>41.92528</lat>
      <lon>-87.70238</lon>
      <heading>122</heading>
    </train>
  </route>
</data>
```

The following code gets the train number for blue or red:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
soup.select_one('route[name="blue"] train rn').get_text()
soup.select_one('route[name="red"] train rn').get_text()
```

The `select` and `select_one` functions allow css-selectors (even in xml) to select data. To filter on attributes of a tag, use `tagname[attrname="attrvalue"]`.

If you want to transform that xml into a python data structure, something like this could work:

```
from typing import *
import bs4


def xml_to_py(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup) -> Dict[str, Dict[int, Dict[str, str]]]:
    data = {}
    for route in soup.select('route'):
        route_data = data[route.get('name')] = {}
        for train in route.select('train'):
            train_number = int(train.select_one('rn').get_text())
            train_data = {
                tag.name: tag.get_text()
                for tag in
                train.select('*')
            }
            route_data[train_number] = train_data
    return data
```

Called with a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` instance of the xml above, it would result in this dictionary:

```
{
    'blue': {
        134: {
            'arrT': '20180117 22:42:47',
            'destNm': 'Forest Park',
            'destSt': '30077',
            'flags': '',
            'heading': '122',
            'isApp': '0',
            'isDly': '0',
            'lat': '41.92528',
            'lon': '-87.70238',
            'nextStaId': '40570',
            'nextStaNm': 'California',
            'nextStpId': '30112',
            'prdt': '20180117 22:40:47',
            'rn': '134',
            'trDr': '5'
        }
    },
    'red': {
        830: {
            'arrT': '20180117 22:42:16',
            'destNm': '95th/Dan Ryan',
            'destSt': '30089',
            'flags': '',
            'heading': '176',
            'isApp': '1',
            'isDly': '0',
            'lat': '41.85532',
            'lon': '-87.63133',
            'nextStaId': '41000',
            'nextStaNm': 'Cermak-Chinatown',
            'nextStpId': '30194',
            'prdt': '20180117 22:41:16',
            'rn': '830',
            'trDr': '5'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: If I want to select another train('rn') from the same paragraph of route = red, will the same commands work as well?